# Dualizing cochain complex and Hochschild complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, loop-spaces

In Cohen and Jones' paper on string topology(A homotopic realization of string topology), they explain the relation between loop homology and Hochschild cohomology of singular cochain complex.

They first state a theorem of loop cohomology and Hochschild homology, 
$$H^\ast(LM) \simeq HH_\ast(C^\ast(M))$$
But after that, they get chain complex by dualizing cochain complex. (which are not finite dimensional or finitely generated)

I googled on this and found Cohen and Voronov's notes on string topology, which says that the following are obvious identification
$$Hom(C^\ast(X)^{\otimes q+1},k) \simeq Hom(C^\ast(X)^{\otimes q},C_\ast(X))$$
Is there any reason that chain complex of simply connected space is reflexive?

I first thought they may go around the minimal model, but they are using integer coefficient in the original paper (25p.).